# Pandas new column replace only show specific pattern value in new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
Index value
  1    880770000-t-ptt-018-108
  2    Nan
  3    760770000-t-ptm-001-107
  4    Date
  5    11/20/2020
  6    607722991-t-ptr-001-888
  7    NaN
  8    Date
  9    10/25/2020
  10   12/30/2019
  11    967722944-t-ptq-020-888
```

I want this in next column specific pattern values to be only shown in new column in same dataframe and other values to be replace by NaN like this. the original table has 200k rows and 22 columns the pattern has above 5000 combinations.

```
Index value
  1    880770000-t-ptt-018-108
  2    Nan
  3    760770000-t-ptm-001-107
  4    NaN
  5    Nan
  6    607722991-t-ptr-001-888
  7    NaN
  8    NaN
  9    NaN
  10   NaN
  11    967722944-t-ptq-020-888
```

Comment: Will all rows with correct pattern always have `-t-`? or it can be something else as well?

Comment: `df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x if "-t-" in x else np.NaN)` Assuming "-t-" pattern is present in the values you want to keep

Comment: this works fine but the column on which I am doing this operation has 'object' type so when I apply this code it giving as error of ""TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x if "-t-" in x else np.NaN)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `does not provide an answer to the question`

Comment: Does it mean we can't have 1 line answers on stack overflow? If there any guidelines that helps differentiate a comment from an answer please point it out, I'd be happy to adhere to that

Comment: Yes you can but it gets flagged by users or bots due to low quality answer. Provide merely some context would do so we can learn from it. Or if you don't care about rep post it as comment. EoR.

Comment: Added it as a comment instead in that case. Should i delete this answer then?

Comment: No. Do not delete your Answer. If it answers the Question it should be posted as an Answer, *not* in a comment. Answering in comments is *discouraged*. A one-liner is an Answer. Though it's preferable if you explain why your one-liner works. cc @PareshMangukiya